# How to import an existing MySQL database of an application to RDS AWS

Tags: mysql, import, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an existing application that is written in `PHP` and the database used is `MySQL`. The application is running fine on an `ec2` instance. I want to migrate the database on `AWS RDS`.

What is the best way to do that?  Do I need to modify anything in the application?

Any lead is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need to change the `hostname` of the database in your PHP application to point to the RDS hostname. It looks something like this:

```
<your-database-name>.ckeebpnindwb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
```

If you changed the username, password and name of the database when you created your RDS instance, you also need to change that information in your PHP application.

If you need to migrate the data the easiest way to do it is like this (from the Linux shell where your application is running):

```
mysqldump -u<your-username> -p <database-name> > database-name-dump.sql
mysql -u<rds-username> -p -h<rds-hostname> -e "CREATE DATABASE <database-name>;"
mysql -u<rds-username> -p -h<rds-hostname> database-name < database-name-dump.sql
```

Comment: the application is running fine on the ec2 server. I need to reconfigure it agian on a new server ? or these changes can be made on the existing server ?

Comment: i have not created the DB instance. can you please guide me how to do all the things from scratch ?

Comment: I have created the dbinstance. Now what should be thye next step.

Comment: You need to migrate the data from the MySQL database on your EC2 instance to the RDS instance.  Follow the steps above.

Comment: i have imported the database dunp on my machine (local machine), then what should be the nxt step

Comment: do i need to create the rds user i mysql on my local machine?

Comment: also its taking too long 'mysql -u<rds-username> -p -h<rds-hostname> -e "CREATE DATABASE <database-name>;' for this command to get executed !!

Comment: If the database is large, it's gonna take some time :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49913/discussion-between-user3086014-and-rico)

Comment: From the command line `mysql -u<rds-username> -p -h<rds-hostname>`

Comment: Then type: `SHOW DATABASES;`

Comment: when im trying to login as rds user im getting this error :`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'awsuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Right password? How did you import the database in first place?

Comment: i used this command `mysql -u<rds-username> -p -h<rds-hostname> -e "CREATE DATABASE <database-name>;`

Comment: Literally that ? Or you substituted the values?

Comment: when i am using `mysql -h testdbinstance.cwucj0efbeuu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u awsuser -p` command i m getting this error : `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'testdbinstance.cwucj0efbeu                                                                                        u.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)`

Comment: i have imported the db in rds , now at   application level what changes should i make?

Comment: In your php configs check for the old database connection string and change it to the RDS one

Comment: i have this `php.ini` file. here there are three fields which needs to be modified : `dbhost`, `dbname`, `server ip`? what should be there value ?

Comment: dbhost=<rds-host>, dbname=<your database name>, dbpasswd=<your db password> .. those are the ones required I believe

Comment: i have used this : `dbhost =testdbinstance.cwucj0efbeuu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`, `dbname=rdsdatabase`. but when i try to connect to application ,i get this error : `mysqli_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'testdbinstance.cwucj0efbeuu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (13).`

Comment: kindly help rico im stuck here :(

Comment: no rico nothing is really working out. even after giving the correct values im getting error

Comment: i have a query, if i have database at rds is it mandatory to have database on the local instance or even i dont have the database on my ec2 instance the application would run !!!

Comment: the application is running rico but  have a query, if i have database at rds is it mandatory to have database on the local instance or even i dont have the database on my ec2 instance the application would run !!!